# Evaluating and explaining what JavaScript variables mean

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-declaration

I am doing GCSE Computing and as one of my tasks I have to evaluate a piece of code and I am stuck at a certain point, I am trying to describe what a variable does and I am having trouble doing so. here is the function with the variable I am trying to explain:

```
function validateForm() {
    var result = true;
    var msg="";
}
```

I am trying to explain what the `var msg="";` does but I cannot find a way to put it into words, I have tried googling my problem but I cannot find any solution.

Comment: obviously, var msg = ''; creates a new variable in memory and assigns an empty value to it!

Comment: Initializes the variable to an empty string?

Comment: I don't think anyone here will want to answer your homework. Understanding certain basics will be very important later on. I'd suggest looking at this to help out:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: @EnigmaRM - I'd suggest you look at this - http://w3fools.com

Comment: @EnigmaRM i couldnt find anything of real use on that page

Comment: @Lix not sure why I need to look at that. I'm aware that people have mixed feelings towards W3, but the information they have on JS variables is accurate

Comment: @user3561394, look at "JavaScript Data Types" and also "Declaring (Creating) JavaScript Variables" section of the page.

Comment: @EnigmaRM  think i've found the source of my confusion, when it says var msg="" does this mean that it is a variable message or that the variable is called msg?

Comment: exactly. `msg` is the name of the variable. the stuff to the right of the `=` is what you're putting inside the `msg` variable.

Comment: @EnigmaRM - a resource containing partially accurate information on some areas, some better information on others and some blatantly bad advice is no resource that I would recommend spreading. There are many less controversial resources out there...

Comment: Do you know what `""` is?

Comment: @EnigmaRM yes, inside of those you will enter what you want to appear inside the previously stated 'thing' for example alert("qwerty")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments, you were able to identify that `msg` is the name of the variable. `var` indicates that we are creating or declaring a new variable, what follows immediately after `var` is the name of the variable.

The `=` acts as an assignment operator. And it assigns things that are on the right side to what is on the left side.

In [W3Schools > JavaScript Data Types](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp), we see the following:

> In JavaScript a text like "John Doe" is called a string.

So in your code, `""` is a string - in this case it's just empty.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, go ahead and mark it as the accepted answer. That way others will know your question has been resolved. 
If it doesn't fully answer your question, you don't have to accept it. That way you'll get others that may still want to post an answer later.

Comment: I'll mark it now as this has helped in the writeup of my coursework, thanks again.